# Unattended upgrades calls my machine "localhost" instead of its hostname

Tags: debian, security, email, upgrade, unattended-upgrades

On some of my machines, unattended upgrades sends an email to tell me a reboot is required, and says:

```
[reboot required] unattended-upgrades result for localhost: SUCCESS
```

While on others, it specifies the correct hostname instead of localhost. Where can I change this to make it specify the hostname correctly?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, it uses the `127.0.0.1` or `::1` in `/etc/hosts`.

Lines like:

```
127.0.0.1  server.yourdomain.xx server localhost
::1 server.yourdomain.xx server localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

makes it ouput messages with `server.yourdomain.xx`
Tested on Debian testing

Comment: That seems to be it.

Answer (score 2):

On our systems it would have seemed to be due to differences in how the `/usr/bin/unattended-upgrade` python3 script tries to figure out its host's name.

On some machines (Ubuntu 18.04) it does:

```py
import os

#...

def host():
    # type: () -> str
    return os.uname()[1]
```

... whereas on newer machines (Ubuntu 22.04) it does:

```py
import socket

#...

def host():
    # type: () -> str
    return socket.getfqdn()
```

It is the latter version of `host()` that simply returns `"localhost"` because that's what [`socket.getfqdn()` without arguments returns](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getfqdn).

This change to the `unattended-upgrade` script was [introduced](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/pull/132) between versions [`1.3` and `1.4`](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/compare/1.3...1.4#diff-02d1cef5a9e7d06bc0b28bf65cc87136a5d1878a74add1b8248b9b833f702bafR970).

[That pull-request already includes some discussion](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/pull/132#issuecomment-761546496) about it introducing the observed `localhost` regression, and it also hints at a workaround that does indeed work:

Instead of listing the desired hostname in `/etc/hosts` as:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1       my-hostname
```

... list it as:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1       my-hostname
```

... all I need now, is an understanding of *why* using `127.0.1.1` instead of `127.0.0.1` makes this work ...

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_hostname_resolution does serve to provide some extra credibility towards the correctness of the solution but for me it still fails to supply sufficient background as to the mechanisms involved and rationale.

[The manpage to `hostname`(1) has a section on the FQDN](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/hostname/hostname.1.en.html#THE_FQDN) that helps getting a grip on the intricacies of name resolving:

> The recommended method of setting the FQDN is to make the hostname be an alias for the fully qualified name using `/etc/hosts`, DNS, or NIS. For example, if the hostname was "`ursula`", one might have a line in `/etc/hosts` which reads
>
> ```
> 127.0.1.1 ursula.example.com ursula
> ```
>
> Technically: The FQDN is the name `getaddrinfo`(3) returns for the host name returned by `gethostname`(2). The DNS domain name is the part after the first dot.
>
> Therefore it depends on the configuration of the resolver (usually in `/etc/host.conf`) how you can change it. Usually the hosts file is parsed before DNS or NIS, so it is most common to change the FQDN in `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the content of the relevant file: [`etc/mailname`](https://wiki.debian.org/EtcMailName):

[Debian policy says](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#mail-transport-delivery-and-user-agents):

> If your package needs to know what hostname to use on (for example)
> outgoing news and mail messages which are generated locally, you
> should use the file `/etc/mailname`. It will contain the portion after
> the username and @ (at) sign for email addresses of users on the
> machine (followed by a newline).

Usually that's the FQDN name (the *long* name) of the server as resolved by other systems.

To make things simple, just reconfigure the relevant package. For the Debian 10's default *exim4* package it's actually [`exim4-config`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/exim4-config):

```
dpkg-reconfigure -pcritical exim4-config
```

`-pcritical` ensures probably no question will be asked. You can omit it or lower it up to `-plow` to see some or all of these questions.

As OP is not using *exim4* but [*msmtp*](https://packages.debian.org/stable/msmtp), for this case, the configuration can be triggered with:

```
dpkg-reconfigure msmtp
```

If this was never done before it's important the first question's (`Create a system wide configuration file?`) answer is Yes, in order to get the followup questions.

It also appears that contrary to *exim4*, the configuration script (once installed, in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/msmtp.config`) doesn't check for `/etc/mailname`, thus not following the recommanded Debian policy.

Comment: I'm using msmtp for emails. Actually, in both machines (that say localhost and the other that says hostname) have the correct hostname in `/etc/mailname`. The msmtp config file doesn't have any hostname. Any ideas?

Comment: While it appears there is provision to submit the hostname through debconf (and dpkg-reconfigure), there doesn't appeart to be any use of /etc/mailname. Looks to me like a policy violation (except it's a "should", not a "must")

Comment: Just tested: `dpkg-reconfigure msmtp` does ask for an hostname IF the first question's answer is yes ("Create a system wide configuration file?"), else there won't be any configuration done.

Comment: This question is really confusing from msmtp in `dpkg-reconfigure`. It says "SMTP server hostname", but does it mean the localhost server or the one in the configuration? I have to visit the configuration documentation and see what that means. I also looked into `/var/lib/dpkg/info/msmtp.config`, it exists, but there's nothing that indicates a hostname. Not sure how msmtp works at all at this point.